# How to avoid Webflow.css gets in conflict with Timepicker.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to implement timePiker.js but it has conflicts with Webflow. It is supposed to be like the next image.
[image]

But if I combined timepicker.css and webflow.css it doesn't work correctly.

[image]

As you can see the timepicker is creating a list. I suppose that it doesn`t work because the list is getting the style from webflow. So what I did was to modify the timepicker.js to create the list calling another CSS class. And I add that new class in the timepiker.css. But It didn`t work.

[image]

timepicker.css

```
.ignoreBoostrapt{

  }
```

timepicker.js

```
     /** hours **/
  for (; u < 4; u++) {
    ii = i + v;
    hours_html.push('<ol class=\"ignoreBoostrapt\">');
    for (; i < ii; i++) {
      hours_html.push([
        '<li class=\"ignoreBoostrapt\"><a ', VARS.attr.hour, '="', i, '">', i, '</a></li>'
      ].join(''));
    }
    hours_html.push('</ol>');
  }
```

Comment: share your console log

Comment: There`s no error, It is showed like that for the webflow.css which has a slyle for the <ol>  **ol {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 40px;
}**
What I did was comment the code in order to work, but I would like to use  other solution